# krajee Bootstrap File Input - Allow only square images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [bootstarp fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) plugin in my project. I need to upload images only those are square in size(same width and height). Is there any solution available?

I don't want to set any fixed width and height.

Comment: Just limit it to square is a bit harsh. it's forcing user to edit there pictures. I think you should crop the images using canvas or something

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily get the image's height and width.
Then do the validation in your client script.

Comment: Thank you. Instead of doing validation by own script, I just wanted to know that is there any dedicated option available in the plugin itself for this kind of common problems. that's why I posted this question.